# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db'

Tags: python, mysql, docker

I am trying to run python backend with mysql database  in docker container locally and stumble upon the error when I run `docker-compose up` command

> backend_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect
> to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")

My **Docker** file:

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33066:3306
```

In settings.py

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mysql',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Comment: The host name in docker-compose usually contains the folder name and an underscore.

Comment: I don't know if I understood your correctly, but it worked. I added hostname to DB in docker-compose.yml and the error disappeared

Comment: If you run `docker-compose up -d`, wait 30-60 seconds, and run it again, does it work the second time?

Comment: huh, no it does not, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: To be precise, it works randomly, the third time it also started my server and I successfully did migrations. Sometimes I cant connect db, sometimes I can. I work with docker containers for the first time and I have no clue at the moment what affects the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In **docker-compose.yml** I had to add

> hostname: 'db'

like that:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    hostname: 'db'
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33066:3306
```

and it worked well

**UPDATE:**

Not really. When I run docker-compose the second time I get the same error